# jQuery: Not recognizing values set during CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I have the following function:

```
var height = $('.fade').outerHeight();

function fadeIt() {
    var fade = function() {
        var opcty = (height - window.scrollY) / height;

        if (opcty >= 0) {
            console.log(opcty);
            $('.fade').css('opacity', opcty);
        }
    };

    $(window).on('scroll', fade);
}
```

It should 'map' the opacity of a div to the scroll position. Actually, it even works! But not in combination with a CSS animation where the opacity is set. I believe it is because jQuery does not recognize the values from the CSS animation, but I am not sure. How can I make this work?
In the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XaufD/1/), I marked the two CSS rules that need to be removed to see that the function works.

Answer (score 1):

ammm i edited this and it works

```
.fade {
position: fixed;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;}

var height = $('.fade').outerHeight();function fadeIt() {    var fade = function() {
    var opcty = (height - window.scrollY) / height;

    if (opcty >= 0) {
        console.log(opcty);
        $('.fade').css({opacity: (height - window.scrollY) / height});
    }
};

$(window).on('scroll', fade);}fadeIt();
```

and this way it works, buuutt, it works better if you change .css to .animate and add 250 time, byeee.

Comment: +1 This looks identical to a Fiddle I started to make, complete with 100px fixed red div!

Comment: But this way the CSS animation is completely removed which is not an option.

Comment: well, then add a jquery animation, so you´ll have a crossbrowser animation, and also the scroll animation . . .